# Azure function is not uploading file in blob storage using user assigned identity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

Added user assigned identity in both function app and in blob storage account as "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role. Code works fine with adding outbound ip address of function app in storage account. But want to use user assigned identity.

I am getting error "One or more errors occurred. (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)"

Anybody faced this issue before? Appreciate your help in advance.

```
            StorageCredentials storageCredential = new StorageCredentials(AccountName, AccessKey);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredential, true);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("rawzone");
            BlobRequestOptions requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new NoRetry() };
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("test");

            string result = "writing test file " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(result).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test in my site and it works very well. You can refer to the following steps to do it.

1.Create my user-assigned managed identity and add `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the identity.

[image]

2.In azure function enable user-assign managed identity and add the user identity you create before.

3.In azure function http trigger and the following code in function which will [use user managed identity](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-with-azure-storage-and-managed-service-identity). The code you provided is using storage credential and it will always work well.

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri("https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net"), storageCredentials);

CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
BlobRequestOptions requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new NoRetry() };
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("hello.txt");

string result = "writing test file " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(result).Wait();
```

4.To control the process, use a connection string passed to the `AzureServiceTokenProvider` constructor or specified in the [`AzureServicesAuthConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) environment variable.

Click you user identity and get its application Id.

```
RunAs=App;AppId={ClientId of user-assigned identity}
```

[image]

5.Then run azure function, and it will write text in to blob.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for @Joey Cai for looking in to my issue. Your code works perfectly if there is no any firewall set up on storage account. Did you try with "All network" or "Selected Network" setting in "Firewalls and virtual networks" of storage account?. It works fine with All Network setting only. Does it require to have identity, function app and storage account in same subscription or location?

Comment: I am getting access token but it is throwing same error at blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(result).Wait(); My identity is having "Storage Blob Data Contributor" access only. Once again thank you for looking in to this issue.

Comment: I have also marked checkbox for Exception "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" on Selected Network setting.

Comment: Why do you want to use firewall? Do you want only function app can access azure storage?

Comment: It's organization policy. Resources in virtual network only should able to access storage account. They are saying with Exception "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account". You should be able to access storage account.

Comment: Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions).

Comment: Azure function service is not listed under trusted Microsoft services to access storage account using System Managed Identity. That means there is no any provision for azure function to access storage account having firewall enabled.

Comment: Yes, Azure function is not included in it.

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click checkbox and turn it green. Thanks.